# Create recursive structure from flatten DFS structure

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search, flatten

### Problem

I have the following tree:

```
      2
     / \
    3   5
   /   / \ 
  6   4   1
```

that is represented in the following way and **order**:

```
id    parent
------------
2     null
3     2
6     3
5     2
4     5
1     5
```

### Purpose:

Store this flatten tree in a recursive structure in **O(n)** (O(n*log(n)) is acceptable, but not very good) (I know how to solve it in **O(n^2)**, but I stored data in that DFS order to be able to "parse" it in a more efficient way). E.g.:

```
class R {
    int id;
    List<R> children;
}
```

that looks like this in a JSON form:

```
{
    id: 2,
    children: [
            {
                id: 3,
                children: { ... }             
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                children: { ... }
            }
    ]
}
```

**How** can I do this? The programming language is not important, because I can translate it in Java.

---

### Java code:

```js
R r = new R();
Map<Long, Line> map = createMap2();
List<Line> vals = new ArrayList<Line>(map.values());
r.id = vals.get(0).id;
vals.remove(0);
r.children = createResource(vals, r.id);
...
private static List<R> createResource(List<Line> l, Long pid) {
    List<R> lr = new ArrayList<R>();
    if ( l.size() > 0 ) {           
        Long id = l.get(0).id;
        Long p = l.get(0).pid;
        l.remove(0);
        if ( pid.equals(p) ) {
            R r = new R();
            r.id = id;
            r.children = createResource(l, id);
            lr.add(r);
        }
        else {
            return createResource(l, pid);   // of course, this is not ok
        }
    }
    return lr;
}
```

The problem in the code above is that only `2`, `3` and `6` are stored in the recursive structure (class R). I want to **store the whole flatten tree structure** (many Line objects) in that **recursive structure** (R object), not only some of nodes.

P.S.: The problem is simplified. I'm not interested in a specific solutions because there are many fields involved and thousands of entries. I am also interested in solutions that work fine for the worst case scenarios (different kind of trees) because this is the user's guarantee.

Comment: What's the questions exactly, you want to convert the id/parent list to Nodes with children? Also, will your data involve mostly balanced  trees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution based on that "DFS" order.

This approach works even if I use a list of "Line" objects or a map.

```
private static List<R> createResource(List<Line> l, Long pid) {
    List<R> lr = new ArrayList<R>();
    for ( Line line : l ) { 
        if ( line is a children ) {
            R r = new R();
            r.id = id;
            l.remove(0);
            r.children = createResource(l, line.id);                
            lr.add(r);
        }
    }
    return lr;
}
```

It seems to be in O(n^2) because there is a `for` loop + recursion for all elements, but it is in **O(n)** . Thanks to DFS order, the next element for which `createResource` is called is on the first position ( 0 -> **O(1)** ). Because the recursion takes every element => the complexity is **O(n)**.

But if the order is not the DFS order (maybe a `Map` that is not `LinkedHashMap` is involved), I recommend the solution that contains arrays for parents. (according to גלעד ברקן )

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this? In the first pass, hash the parents as arrays of their children and identify the root; in the second, begin with the root and for each of its children, insert a new object, with its own children and so on:

To take your example, the first pass would generate

```
parent_hash = {2:[3,5], 3:[6], 5:[4,1]}
root = 2
```

The second pass would go something like:

```
object 2 -> object 3 -> object 6
         -> object 5 -> object 4
                     -> object 1
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I'm trying to work on another approach (I edited the post), but if I can't do it, I'll try to create additional objects according to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that once an entry doesn't satisfy `p == pid` condition it is lost forever. Instead of losing entries you should break the loop and return immediately. The offending entry shall also be returned and handled by a proper instance of `R` upstream.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I adjusted the post to a simplified version that uses arrays. I will try to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily represent the whole tree in an array, since each node of the tree can be represented by an index in the array. For a binary tree, the children of index *i* would be at index 2*i+1 and index 2*i+2. It would then be simple to convert the array to any other representation. The array itself would be a space-efficient representation for balanced trees, but would waste a lot of space for very unbalanced trees. (This should not matter unless you're dealing with a very large amount of data.)

If you need a memory-efficient way for large unbalanced trees, then it would make sense to use the standard Node-representation of trees. To convert from your list, you could use a HashMap as גלעד ברקן suggested. However, if the id's of the nodes are mostly continuous (like the example where they're from 1 to 6), you could also just use an array where each index of the array *i* is used to store a Node with an id of *i*. This will let you easily find a parent node and assign it children nodes as they're created.

(cf. my [Trees tutorial](https://www.learneroo.com/modules/32/nodes/227) for storing trees as arrays.)